# Compression for ActiveMQ to ActiveMQ

Tags: activemq-classic

I do have two ActiveMQ brokers connected and do forward messages from broker one to broker two automatically. This is done by following configuration:

```
<networkConnectors>
    <networkConnector name="linkToRemote" uri="static(tcp://172.19.63.3:61616)?jms.useCompression=true" staticBridge="true"> 
        <staticallyIncludedDestinations>
           <queue physicalName="xyz.queue"/>
        </staticallyIncludedDestinations> 
    </networkConnector>
</networkConnectors>
```

Everything except the compression is working fine. My messages are 180KB in size. I have seen that the traffic is not compressed at all. Is `jms.useCompression=true` not functional? Has someone any alternatives to compress the traffic between two brokers? What about ssh tunnels if compression in ActiveMQ this is not working? My ActiveMQ version is 5.14.13.

Comment: Justin, thank you very much !

Comment: Following the advise at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-3787 I tried to set just uri="static(tcp://172.19.63.3:61616)?useCompression=true" and uri="static(tcp://172.19.63.3:61616)?connection.useCompression=true" Both did not worked also.

Comment: Add any additional information to the original question rather than in the comments.

Comment: Hi, I am now using autossh and compression. This combination works great.

Answer (score 2):

I am now using autossh and compression. This combination works great. Active MQ does not compress the messages well if we use many small messages as it does not share a common compression dictionary.